# How do I add link to cells using HTML::TagTree?

Tags: html, perl, html-table

I am using HTML::TagTree as it seems to create the html file for table easily. I want to add html links to the text within some cells.

From the documentation provided [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TagTree), I am not able to get a clear answer about how to add a new tag for the text inside a cell. Here's my code.

Main line to focus on: $new_row->td($1,'style=text-align:center'*,'a:href="second_page.html"'*)

I don't think I clearly understand how to add more tags and attributes. Can someone please help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TagTree;

my $filename = 'list.txt';
my $html = HTML::TagTree->new('html');   # Define the top of the tree of objects.
my $head = $html->head();                # Put a 'head' branch on the tree.
my $body = $html->body();                # Put a 'body' branch on the tree
$head->title("Report");
$head->meta('', 'name=author CONTENT="xxx"');
$body->div->h1('Main page name');           # Example of method chaining to create
                                         # a long branch.
my $table = $body->table('', 'width=100% border=1');
my $row1 = $table->tr();
$row1->td('Feature Code','style=background-color:khaki;text-align:center');
$row1->td('Feature Name','style=background-color:khaki;text-align:center');
$row1->td('% completed','style=background-color:khaki;text-align:center');

open(my $fh, '<', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while (my $row = <$fh>){
    if($row =~ m/([.\d]+): (.+)/){
        my $new_row = $table->tr();
        $new_row->td($1,'style=text-align:center','a:href="page_for_each_item.html"');  
        $new_row->td($2);  
    }
}


# Print to STDOUT the actual HTML representation of the tree
$html->print_html();
```

Comment: Did you try ... `$body->link`? (or `$body->anchor`...?)  Or perhaps `$td->anchor` (or `link`), where you'd need to make `$td` first? Docs do show method signatures, in a (rather condensed :) paragraph. Note that the module appears to last have been active 4 and a half years ago.

Comment: It seems that you have data in a flat file and want to write it in a HTML table?  The `HTML::Template` can be useful for that.  May be the best way to generate HTML in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tries I think I found one way of doing it:

```
my $new_row = $table->tr();
my $text = $html->object();
$text->a($original_text,"href=second_page.html");
$new_row->td($text,'style=text-align:center');
```

Comment: Great.  I'd add a statement on what those `$1` and `$2` are, to complete the it as an answer. (If that solves it you can mark it as accepted as well, but perhaps leave it first, for a day or so, as other people are more likely to visit the page if the question isn't listed as "asnwered" (green); then there may be other useful answers).